# Closing a word-document while Word is open

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a C# code that creates word documents and then close them.
The closing code is this:

```
 // Close and release the Document object.
 if (wordDocument != null)
 {
     ((_Document)wordDocument).Close(ref oFalse, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing);
     wordDocument = null;
 }

 // Quit Word and release the ApplicationClass object.
 if (wordApplication != null)
 {
      wordApplication.Quit(ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing);
      wordApplication = null;
 }
```

The problem is that if Word is already open in my computer, this code doesn't work and then I find many open documents on my computer.
Does anyone knows what's the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an explanation about application instances here:
[Process.Kill() issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930914/process-kill-issue)

"When you start a new instance of Internet Explorer it will try to see if Internet Explorer is already running. If that is true the URL is opened in the already running instance and the new instance exits immediately."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem, sometimes the document or word would not close. And then I had trouble with all the document opening after that. The thing I did was something like that :

```
try
{
wordDocument.Close(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
}
catch
{
// do something         
} 
finally
{
wordApplication.Quit(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
}
```

Comment: no exception is thrown so it won't help, I close the wordApplication anyway. Look at my code.

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't investigate more on that problem, I switched to XML to open docx, because it is easier and I have less problem that way.